# Distance computation between (M,N) and (N,) arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I am calculating Euclidean distances in python. I want to learn how to calculate it without using a for loop. Here is my code,

```
import numpy as np
import random
A = np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 5))
B = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
for i in range(10):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(A[i]-B)
    print("Distances: ", dist)
```

Is there anyway in which I can use advanced indexing or any other techniques to calculate the distances without using a for loop? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Most straight-forward one with `np.linalg.norm` using its `axis` param and also leveraging `broadcasting` would be -

```
np.linalg.norm(A-B,axis=1)
```

**Approach #2 :** With `einsum` -

```
subs = A - B
out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs))
```

**Approach #3 :** Using `(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab` formula to leverage `matrix-multiplication` with `np.dot` and `np.inner` -

```
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A, A) + np.inner(B,B) - 2*A.dot(B))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the [Frobenius Norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) explicitly:

```
res = (np.abs(A - B)**2).sum(1)**0.5
```

This is the default for [`np.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html). Here's a demo:

```
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 5))
B = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]

res = (np.abs(A - B)**2).sum(1)**0.5

array([4.89897949, 5.38516481, 5.29150262, 5.47722558, 5.        ,
       5.56776436, 6.244998  , 2.23606798, 5.56776436, 4.47213595])
```